# Is it possible to have tslint type check enum types?

Tags: javascript, typescript, tslint

Is it possible to have tslint throw an error when a variable is assigned a value that is incompatible with its enum type?

For example:

```
export enum Gender {
    male = 1,
    female = 2
}

export class User {
    id: number;
    gender: Gender;
}

var user = new User();

user.gender = Gender.Male; // OK

user.gender = 3; // Currently is OK, desired result: TYPE ERROR

if (user.gender === Gender.Male) {} // OK

if (user.gender === 3) {} // Currently is OK, desired result: TYPE ERROR
```

Comment: Found this after your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52873462/typescript-strict-enum-checking, the linked issue (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26362) explains the background behind the compiler NOT picking this up.

A TSLint rule to do this instead would be handy though, so +1 to your question.

Comment: @Tom I submitted a feature request here: https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4329