# TypeScript strict enum checking

Tags: typescript, enums

Is there any way to enforce strict usage of `enum`? Some examples:

```
enum AnimalType {
  Cat,
  Dog,
  Lion
}

// Example 1
function doSomethingWithAnimal(animal: AnimalType) {
  switch (animal) {
    case Animal.Cat: // ...
    case Animal.Dog: // ...
    case 99: // This should be a type error
  }
}

// Example 2
someAnimal.animalType = AnimalType.Cat; // This should be fine
someAnimal.animalType = 1; // This should be a type error
someAnimal.animalType = 15; // This should be a type error
```

Basically, if I say that something has an `enum` type, then I want the TypeScript compiler (or alternatively tslint) to make sure that it is used correctly. With the current behavior I don't really understand the point of enums as they are not enforced. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an intentional design decison on the TypeScript team's part to enable bitflags, see [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26362) for more details. Reading that issue and the various ones it links to, I get the distinct sense they wish they'd separated enums and bitflags originally but can't get themselves around to the place of making the breaking change / adding a flag.

It works the way you want it to with a **string** `enum` rather than a numeric one:

```
enum AnimalType {
  Cat = "Cat",
  Dog = "Dog",
  Lion = "Lion"
}

// Example 1
function doSomethingWithAnimal(animal: AnimalType) {
  switch (animal) {
    case AnimalType.Cat: // Works
    case AnimalType.Dog: // Works
    case "99": // Error: Type '"99"' is not assignable to type 'AnimalType'. 
  }
}

// Example 2
const someAnimal: { animalType: AnimalType } = {
  animalType: AnimalType.Dog
};
let str: string = "foo";
someAnimal.animalType = AnimalType.Cat; // Works
someAnimal.animalType = "1"; // Type '"1"' is not assignable to type 'AnimalType'.
someAnimal.animalType = str; // Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'AnimalType'.
```

[Live Example in the Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=enum%20AnimalType%20%7B%0A%20%20Cat%20%3D%20%22Cat%22%2C%0A%20%20Dog%20%3D%20%22Dog%22%2C%0A%20%20Lion%20%3D%20%22Lion%22%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Example%201%0Afunction%20doSomethingWithAnimal(animal%3A%20AnimalType)%20%7B%0A%20%20switch%20(animal)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20case%20AnimalType.Cat%3A%20%2F%2F%20Works%0A%20%20%20%20case%20AnimalType.Dog%3A%20%2F%2F%20Works%0A%20%20%20%20case%20%2299%22%3A%20%2F%2F%20Error%3A%20Type%20'%2299%22'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20'AnimalType'.%20%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Example%202%0Aconst%20someAnimal%3A%20%7B%20animalType%3A%20AnimalType%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20animalType%3A%20AnimalType.Dog%0A%7D%3B%0Alet%20str%3A%20string%20%3D%20%22foo%22%3B%0AsomeAnimal.animalType%20%3D%20AnimalType.Cat%3B%20%2F%2F%20Works%0AsomeAnimal.animalType%20%3D%20%221%22%3B%20%2F%2F%20Type%20'%221%22'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20'AnimalType'.%0AsomeAnimal.animalType%20%3D%20str%3B%20%2F%2F%20Error%3A%20Type%20'string'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20'AnimalType'.)

Comment: Well that's unfortunate... Very strange behavior, in my opinion. I don't like the answer, but I'll accept it! :)

Comment: @Frigo - Yeah. :-) I've added a new first paragraph above that may be useful.